# Comunication between multiple servers using Perfect

Tags: swift, perfect

I am developing server app that requires 2 types of server. 1 master server that will handle load balancing, authentication etc and multiple instances of work servers that will handle actual application logic. I need to be able to communicate between those two type of server. What would be best approach to do that? When I faced this problem last time I used websocket connection and it was working fine, but maybe there is better way (simpler, more efficient, more standard, I don't know) that can be used. I am not backend developer, so I have no idea how this things are usually handled

Comment: What are the work tasks? What kind of data needs to be shared? Are the tasks long running or short? Do they return data to the user or do something else? So many things affect the architecture...

Comment: I am not asking about architecture, I got that figured out. I am more after low level stuff, what kind of protocol to use. I am currently trying to use sockets and it seems like a way to go. I will update a question and perhaps even write an answer when I get a chance to play with it some more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using good ol' TCP sockets. It was bit of a pain to set up because of lack of documentation, but it seems to be working fine.